# Accessing groupby value based on id?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have an array which has  id and  weight information, I want to groupby the array based on the id regarding min and max weight:

```
a= pd.Series(weight).groupby(id).agg(["min", "max"])
```

I want to access each min/ max element based on their id.
My question is how to save and access each min/max value based on keys(id) so that I can access each element?

I use `w_min=a.iloc[0,0]` to access each element, what is the best way of accessing each element?

Comment: Honestly, your code doesn't make much sense. Firstly, `c` is not defined, but it looks like you meant `id`. Next, if I understand your data correctly, `s, r` represent id and weight, but you're saving them in the wrong lists. Next, why are you splitting the data into lists in the first place instead of just putting them in a df? i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'weight'])`

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize `pd.Series(weight).groupby(id)` would work. (Still learning Pandas myself.) It still seems strange to use that instead of a df, but yeah it'll work. Now I'm confused why you don't know how to access data by index. What have you tried that didn't work? Are you familiar with `.loc`?

Comment: Please review it, for accessing elements I use .iloc.It works, I wanted to know what are the other ways.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict) and then you can access your values by key (in this case `id`):

```py
#... code as in your question

out = a.to_dict(orient="index")

print(out)
print(out[5]["min"])  # <-- access by `5` and `min`
```

Prints:

```py
{
    1: {"min": 100, "max": 200},
    3: {"min": 258, "max": 585},
    5: {"min": 89, "max": 632},
}
89
```